# List Iterator previous is not working in Java

Tags: java, list, iterator

I am not sure what causes this issue, but it seems very weird as I am not getting expected results.

```
   datesMap.addAll(yearSubColumn.keySet()); // Having two values:
                                            // 2018-11-11 22:17:32+00:00,
                                            // 2019-04-08 17:53:59+00:00
   ListIterator<String> datesMapIterator = datesMap.listIterator();
   while (datesMapIterator.hasNext()) {
       overallStrength = 0.0f;
       firstDate = datesMapIterator.next();
       String secondDate = datesMapIterator.next();
       System.out.println("SECOND" + secondDate);
       String prevDat = datesMapIterator.previous();
       System.out.println("Prev" + prevDat);
       System.exit(0)
   }
```

Output: `SECOND2019-04-08 17:53:59+00:00 Prev2019-04-08 17:53:59+00:00`

Why I am not getting 2018-11-11 22:17:32+00:00 in **PrevDat**. Is there anything wrong with the data structure?
Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

See the docs on `ListIterator` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html).

In your case, your list is something like `["2018", "2019"]` (shortened for brevity).

When you first create the iterator, it's "cursor" is positioned as:

```
   2018   2019
 ^
cursor
```

Per the docs, this means that `next` will return "2018" (i.e. `firstDate` is "2018").

After you've called `next` ONCE, iterator is in state like:

```
   2018   2019
        ^
     cursor
```

Now, you call `next` a second time (to get `secondDate`). `next` returns "2019" (since it's the next thing after the cursor). After that call, state is:

```
   2018   2019
               ^
            cursor
```

At this point, you call previous, which returns the element *before* the cursor. As you can see from above diagram, this value will be "2019" which is what your code prints. After the call to `previous`, you will be in this state again:

```
   2018   2019
        ^
      cursor
```

In short, `previous` will return the thing that was just returned by `next` and moves the cursor back by one spot.

Comment: Can you suggest any better way to reach to previous iterating value?

Comment: You already have it, it's stored in `firstDate` :)

Answer (score 2):

As per `ListIterator` document for `next`

Returns the next element in the list and advances the cursor position. This method may be called repeatedly to iterate through the list, or intermixed with calls to previous to go back and forth. (**Note that alternating calls to next and previous will return the same element repeatedly.**)

Since you do next on first element the pointer reaches to second and now if you do previous, it reaches back to second only.

Answer (score 1):

If you **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`previous()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ListIterator.html#previous()), you will find:

> Returns the previous element in the list and moves the cursor position backwards. This method may be called repeatedly to iterate through the list backwards, or intermixed with calls to [next()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ListIterator.html#next()) to go back and forth. (Note that **alternating calls to next and previous will return the same element repeatedly**.)